# Powershell ISE run strangely

Tags: powershell, ide, powershell-ise

I'm new on Powershell scripting and i've one issue.
When i start scripting, my stuff runs well but since yesterday, the script execution runs differently than before.

Now :

- The console print all the variables values when not ask
- Open pop-up for read-host command (this is a console application)
- The securestring isn't decrypt by the application anymore
- "Enter" key must be pressed 2 times to enter values when the script
  runs
- Some commands are not found

Any ideas guys?
Thank you (and excuse my poor english ^^)

Comment: these issues aren't normal at all - the ISE does have different behavior for some things though - can you post the output of `$PSVersionTable` from both console and ISE, and post the code you're seeing the issues with? some things seem like they can definitely be caused by issues in your code.

Comment: It sounds like the ISE is running some kind of startup file.  There are many circumstances that can cause this.  Take a look at the directory where the ISE starts, and look for files that might be startup commands.  This is only one possibility.

Comment: Does this happen when you close and reopen ISE? Your session variable will remaining persistent depending on how you execute your script. Your script might not like being run again in the same window.

Comment: @Walter Mitty : i've look but i saw nothing... Could it be a security rule on my domain?

Comment: @Matt Yes, it happens again when i close/reopen the ISE. I agree, he dosent like being run again in the same window because he print all variables values in the shell during the second run (server name, username and pass... :/)